# Spring IDE does not support with eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use the eclipse version Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2). I have installed the Spring IDE using the market place successfully.

I couldn't create the Spring project using eclipse. There is no option to create the spring project.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: A) tried using a newer version of Eclipse? B) Can you open a spring perspective? What kind of tutorial are you following?

Comment: I couldn't open a Spring perspective. I followed the below link. https://www.mkyong.com/spring/how-to-install-spring-ide-in-eclipse/

Comment: Just to be sure : you restarted eclipse after installing the plugin?

Comment: Yes I did. I un installed the Spring IDE and installed SpringSource Tool Suite. Now an create the project in Spring perspective.